# One proportion Z-test and Chi Square Goodness of Fit should be identical but return different results

Tags: r, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, z-test

My understanding is that a Chi Square Goodness of Fit test and a one-proportion Z-test should have identical p-values and be equivalent (https://youtu.be/-Vssir6yUNQ?si=4-t9Np9h4bedU9xN&t=423). However, when I test them in R, they return different p-values and test statistics. Should the below code be written differently or am I misunderstanding the statistics? I am absolutely stumped why these two examples are not identical!

Reproducible example:

```
# Simulated data: 100 observations of a categorical variable with two levels
observed <- c(45, 55)  # Frequencies for the two categories
expected_prop <- 0.5   # Expected proportion for the first category (null hypothesis)

# Perform one proportion Z-test
prop_test <- prop.test(observed[1], n = sum(observed), p = expected_prop, alternative = "two.sided")
cat("One Proportion Z-Test:\n")
print(prop_test)

# Perform chi-square goodness of fit test
expected <- rep(sum(observed) * expected_prop, length(observed))
chi_square_test <- chisq.test(observed, p = expected, rescale.p = TRUE)
cat("\nChi-Square Goodness of Fit Test:\n")
print(chi_square_test)
```

Correct answer from Demetri (change correction to False):

```
# Load required library
library(stats)

# Simulated data: 100 observations of a categorical variable with two levels
observed <- c(45, 55)  # Frequencies for the two categories
expected_prop <- 0.5   # Expected proportion for the first category (null hypothesis)

# Perform one proportion Z-test
prop_test <- prop.test(observed[1], n = sum(observed), p = expected_prop, alternative = "two.sided", correct = F)
cat("One Proportion Z-Test:\n")
print(prop_test)

# Perform chi-square goodness of fit test
expected <- rep(sum(observed) * expected_prop, length(observed))
chi_square_test <- chisq.test(observed, p = expected, rescale.p = F)
cat("\nChi-Square Goodness of Fit Test:\n")
print(chi_square_test)
```

Comment: Both functions have a “correct” argument that applies a small sample correction. Could you try setting that to False and try again?

Comment: Wow, it looks like that was it! Thanks so much. I don't think I would've realized that on my own

Comment: To help others who might ha e this problem, why don't you post the solution suggested by @DemetriPananos as an answer to this question? It's OK to answer your own question here.

Comment: @EdM the revised post above already includes the suggestion from DemetriPananos ! It is the code segment that says, "Correct answer from Demetri (change correction to False):"

Comment: @JE52 I've posted my answer as an answer below.  If this helped, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because these two functions apply a small sample correction via the `correct` argument.  Try the following:

````
# Load required library
library(stats)

# Simulated data: 100 observations of a categorical variable with two levels
observed <- c(45, 55)  # Frequencies for the two categories
expected_prop <- 0.5   # Expected proportion for the first category (null hypothesis)

# Perform one proportion Z-test
prop_test <- prop.test(observed[1], n = sum(observed), p = expected_prop, alternative = "two.sided", correct = F)
cat("One Proportion Z-Test:\n")
print(prop_test)

# Perform chi-square goodness of fit test
expected <- rep(sum(observed) * expected_prop, length(observed))
chi_square_test <- chisq.test(observed, p = expected, rescale.p = F)
cat("\nChi-Square Goodness of Fit Test:\n")
print(chi_square_test)
```
````